I'm getting InvalidPidMappingException without using transactional producers with Spring Boot and Spring Kafka
Repository in GitHub
Hello! I hope you are doing great!
I'm working in a kubernetes environment, with 3 pods using Spring Boot and Kotlin, and we are using Apache Kafka with Azure Event Hubs. In the last week, our services started to throw the following exception: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidPidMappingException: The producer attempted to use a producer id which is not currently assigned to its transactional id. None of my team are kafka experts, so I read a lot about it and it seems to be a problem of Transactional Kafka, like mentioned here: Medium Article and Spring Kafka Doc.
I don't know much about Spring Kafka (usually I only wrote consumers and producers and it works haha), but according to the documentation, transactional producers are only created inside a @Transactional scope and when it's configured inside application.yaml file (using transaction-id-prefix).
The problem is: We don't configure any transaction-id-prefix in our configuration file (and when the service starts it's logged the producer config and we have transaction.id = null to comprove that) and the producer is not called inside a @Transactional annotated method, it is called inside a @TransactionalEventListener (I don't know if this creates a new transaction).
I'm using spring-boot 3.2.4 and spring-kafka 3.2.3.
The producer is activated inside the event-listener who is triggered when we persists an entity in the database, the event-listener code is below:
    @TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT, classes = [AbstractEvent::class])
    fun publish(event: StaticQRCodeCreatedEvent): Unit {
        val entity = event.aggregate
        producer.produce(buildMessage(entity))
    }

And this is my producer configuration in application.yaml file:
      producer:
        key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        retries: 5
        acks: all
        properties:
          linger.ms: 50
          max.block.ms: 120000

I changed log level to TRACE and DEBUG to understand what is happening, but when the producer is called, spring-kafka logs that "Instantiated an idempotent producer." and debugging the producer's properties the transaction.id is null, proving that the producer isn't a transactional. producer.
And I saw in the logs that the transaction started in the first step (saving the entity before send the event to event-listener) and it is finished before the @TransactionalEventListener method is executed.
Does anyone know how to solve that problem? I fix this just redeploying our pods whenever this exception occurs, but probably there is a smarter solution.

Can you reproduce the steps in a standalone app in a non-Kubernetes environment? If that is the case, please share that app, and we can triage it further. Thanks!

Sure @sobychacko : https://github.com/franciscofeo/spring-kafka-kotlin I created a simple example using the same stack as the project I'm working on and it's close to the same flow. Check the logs and you will see that spring-kafka prints that the producer is an 'idempotent producer' and not transactional.. why am I getting this exception sometimes in my main project?

Didn't get a chance to run the sample, but quickly glancing at the config, I don't see that you are defining a transaction-id-prefix. You need to include that config to activate transactions.

Hi! Yes, my question is about why am I getting this exception if my producers are not transactionals, right? From what I understand, the InvalidPIDMapping only occurs with transactional producers, if I don't define a 'transaction-id-prefix' my producers will not be transactional and there are no kafka transactions. :(

Maybe you need to remove any intentions for transactionality from your code. See here: https://github.com/franciscofeo/spring-kafka-kotlin/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/com/franciscofeo/kotlinkafkaexample/EventListener.kt#L18. This could probably give the framework a hint that you are trying to publish transactionally. I have yet to have a chance to run your app. Please isolate the producer without transactional annotations and see if that resolves the issue.

That's a good point! But when I run the app and I start the flow, the kafka logs that: "Instantiated an idempotent producer", and the transaction.id is null... so this cannot start a transaction, right?

Yeah, something is amiss in the configuration. See if you can isolate the issue to a particular method or configuration. It looks like there is some cross-chat happening between Kafka and DB transactional code.

Ok! I'll try to reproduce this exception, thanks!

Hello, @sobychacko! I'm trying to reproduce this issue but it's very difficult because I don't know how this exception is thrown.... in my application (mentioned in the question, not the standalone app) this only happened once, that is, it's not frequent and we are using event -hubs, I don't know if it changes anything.

Have you tried to log the configuration of the Kafka client in the application?
Maybe enable.idempotence is true, and, in that case, it should have a producerId generated with an expiration:

https://learn.conduktor.io/kafka/idempotent-kafka-producer/
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/event-hubs/apache-kafka-transactions#transactional-producers

